# is it different 'default ' and 'Default' in zend default session namespace?

Tags: zend-framework

I am using sessions in zend framework.

the question is i need to know is there a difference between

```
new Zend_Session_Namespace("default");
```

and

```
new Zend_Session_Namespace("Default");
```

in my application, I have used both, it seems the code is not working correctly, 
if there is a difference, what is the correct one to use.

here is my code

```
<?php
class Admin_DashboardController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    function init()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Add hotelId to default session
     * redirect to admin/hotels if hotelId is not avialble  
     */ 
    public function indexAction()
    {       
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $hotelid = NULL;

            $config_session = new Zend_Session_Namespace("default");
            $config_session->hotelid = $params['id'];

        if(isset($params['id']) && !empty($params['id'])){

        }else{

            //redirect user to select hotels page
            $redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();

            $url = array(
                'action' => 'admin/hotels/index'
            );

            $redirector->gotoRouteAndExit($url);

        }                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `Zend_Session_Namespace` does internally is create a named array inside the `$_SESSION` superglobal. As array keys in PHP are case sensitive, "Default" and "default" will be treated as separate namespaces.

You can use whichever one you want, just be consistent if you expect to use the same data.